# Ways to avoid cross form submission in authenticated pages

Tags: jquery, http-post, pyramid

I'm developing an application and I face the following problem:

An user of the application can have multiple projects. For example project01 and project01. The URL for the project is https://myApp.com/{projectid}.

When the user logs in and access the project page for example https://myApp.com/project01 there is an "Update project" button within a form with method=post action=https://myApp.com/project01 .

The problem: If I use the Browser inspector and change the action to https://myApp.com/project02 and I press the "Update project" button the information of project01 updates project02 because both projects belongs to the same user.

Currently I am avoiding this cross submission by checking in the server side if the HTTP referrer is the same as the current URL being posted. However I would like to know if there are other ways to avoid this problem.

I also tried issuing update tokens stored as session variables and checking if the token is active for update, however if the user has both projects open at the same time in the browser and perform the same edit with the inspector then I cannot control the cross submission.

Comment: The user can always alter or replace your HTML and JavaScript, so I'm not sure there's any way to accomplish what you want.  Also you should tag the question with your server-side and client-side frameworks.

Comment: Why is this behaviour a problem in your app? Why would the user edit the form's action instead of directly going to the other project and making the changes? Is it an attempt of enforcing the permissions on the client side (i.e. the "Update project" button on the project02 is hidden because the user is "forbidden" from making changes, but it's not enforced on the server side?)

Comment: @Sergey, the behavior problem is that users CAN edit the form's action using the browser inspector thus able to overwrite one project with the information of another. Is not a "forbidden" issue because the user can change both projects, but controlling that if the user has "Project one" in the screen and press the update button it will update "Project one" and never another project because it changed the form's action.